# Solidity: Use String as Hex

Tags: hex, solidity

I am new to Solidity and trying some stuff.

I would like to store the defined hex value "ac43fe" in a bytes-variable. Like this it is working fine:

```
bytes memory foo = hex"ac43fe";
```

But instead of doing it directly, I will have the hex-value inside a string. Like:

```
string hex = "ac43fe"
```

Now I am searching for a way, so that I can convert this Hex-value (stored in the string) into a bytes variable.

Thanks a lot for your help.

Best regards,
Pascal

Answer (score -1):

You can convert a value to bytes by doing:

```
bytes <var_name> = bytes(<string_var>);
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I believe this converts the characters of the string into a new bytes array, rather than converting the string into a hex with the same chars as the string. (`"AC43FE"` --> `0xAC43FE`)

Just like `hex"AC43FE"` returns `0xAC43FE`, I believe the question is about doing something like:
`string memory myHexString = "AC4eFE";`
`bytes memory b = abi.encodePacked(hex(myHexString));`

But `hex()` is not a function. I think if I can learn how to use `hex` with a variable, I have my solution and it will close this question on stackoverflow as well.